# Comma usage check

Tags: commas

Would you kindly check the following sentences?

> Please be informed, that we are able to...

or:

> Please be informed, that in order to ...

Is the comma after "informed" grammatically correct, or redundant?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the comma there, because there's no need for a pause; the statement needs to be spoken (and written) continuously.

Comment: Spoken pauses are an unreliable indicator for comma usage. The OP should note that punctuation is a matter of style, and not grammar. Style manuals disagree, but they attempt to provide rules that help the reader parse written text. Most manuals would recommend that a comma not separate a verb (here *be informed*) from a directly-following object (here, the clause introduced by *that*).

Comment: @deadrat - You're right -- style manuals disagree.  They are, especially in the case of comma placement, simply certain people's opinions codified into artificial "rules" which, in most cases, were derived from how those certain people speak and write.  A native speaker of the language generally has an innate sense of how to pace speech in order to most clearly convey the semantic intent, and that sense is a good a guide as most style manuals, for ordinary day-to-day usage.